# get city and temperature values into variables to use in reducer file

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

Im trying to develop a mapreduce program to show the max temperature of a city from a text file.

My Temperatures.txt file have this format:

City1 10

City 2 12

...

And I already have the mapper.py file working like this:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    print line
```

But instead of just do `print line`, I want to do something like this:

```
print '%s\t%s' % (city ,temperature)
```

Because to develop the reducer.py file I need this, so my question is if you know how can I, in my mapper.py file, get each line and put the city name inside my variable city and temperature inside my variable temperature, like this:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:

    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        city = # how can i get this?
        temperature = # how can i get this?
    print line
    # so i can show the resut like this
    print '%s\t%s' % (city ,temperature)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the city and temp are in each line you need to get them from the line:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    city, temperature = line.rsplit(None, 1)
    print '%s\t%s' % (city ,temperature)
```

You should also be using `rsplit` and only splitting once for cities with more than a single word in their name.

If you have empty lines in the file you also need to catch those:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.strip():
        city, temperature = line.rsplit(None, 1)
        print '%s\t%s' % (city ,temperature)
```

Or use  a try/except:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        city, temperature = line.rsplit(None, 1)
        print '%s\t%s' % (city ,temperature)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked! Thanks also for your detailed answer!

Comment: @UserX, no prob, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You could use following code

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    words = line.split()
    if len(words) < 2:
        continue;
    city = words[:-1]
    city = ''.join(city)
    temperature = words[-1]
    print line
    # so i can show the resut like this
    print '%s\t%s' % (city ,temperature)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with your code, Im having: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapper.py", line 4, in <module>
    city = words[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Personally I would use `city = words[:-1]` and `temperature = float(words[-1])` to cope with cities that have multi word names. It would also be worth checking that `len(words) > 1`

Comment: @Steve Barnes Totally agree with you. I will correct my answer.

Comment: @UserX Please, provide input on which you got this error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now its working but with two issues, first I have different spaces between the city name and temperature, and second, there are some citys that have two, three, four, ... words, and in this cases its not working, because for example a city with name and templerature like this "thiscity threewords city2 16.163" I have the city only with thiscity and the temperature with threewords..Im here trying to find a solution for this, do you have any idea?

Comment: @UserX Please, try new code from my answer. I correct problem with multiwords cities.